# Autoposting Radiobuttons in ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postback, radio-button

I'm trying to add a couple of radiobuttons at the top of a View (using ASP.NET MVC).

I want the two radiobuttons (option 1 and option 2) to cause the page to be refreshed/autoposted when changed.

The two radiobuttons live inside a separate .asxc (Menu.ascx), and added with Html.RenderPartial in a List.aspx page. The two options in turn determine if Html.RenderPartial("ListOption1Elements") or Html.RenderPartial("ListOption2Elements") is added to the page.

I've tried adding both Html.RadioButton and using <asp:RadioButtonList>, but haven't got it working properly. Only the last one of those has the AutoPostBack property I need, but it complains about not being inside a  tag.

So, to sum up - how can I add two hardcoded radiobuttons that will cause a postback so that I in my Controller can determine which partial view to render?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postback concept is not supported in ASP.NET MVC as well as server controls in general.

You need to do it manually with JavaScript. Attach a function to the "onclick" event of a radiobutton and make an asynchronous call to a controller action that will simply issue a server side redirect to the same action that generated the view in question.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to "make an asynchronous call to a controller" in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this to do it by javascript:
[Postback on RadioButtonFor in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977655/postback-on-radiobuttonfor-in-mvc)
Or this to do it in Ajax way:
[MVC - Postback on clicking a radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916322/mvc-postback-on-clicking-a-radio-button)