# Show/Hide sections based on radio button selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC 4 web application. I have a view where some sections should be shown/hidden based on the selection of a radio button list (3 radio buttons A), B) , C). )
It seems there is no way to do this without using jquery/javascript ?

According this post:

[Postback on RadioButtonFor in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977655/postback-on-radiobuttonfor-in-mvc)

```
 "There is no server side event occurring when the user changes the selection of a radio button."
```

Can I perform a postback with my radio buttons and show/hide sections based on the selection?

Please, let me know if it can be done without javascript and just pure ASP.NET MVC 4+ code.

Comment: You can do full posts to your server and re-render your page as appropriate.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use jQuery or javascript? Of course you can do this on the server, there is basically no limitation. The question is why...

Comment: Edited my question, please provide a code sample to understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveIndex()
{
    return View();
}
```

Here is the code for view:

```
<div>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveIndex", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post"}, new { id = "MainForm" }))
    {
        @Html.RadioButton("My Radio1", "Radio1", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
        @Html.RadioButton("My Radio2", "Radio2", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
    }
</div>
```