# Postback on CheckedChange

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to filter a list based on some checkboxes, therefore when I (un)check a checkbox I would like to do a postback to the server and do my filtering logic there.

On [Postback on RadioButtonFor in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977655/postback-on-radiobuttonfor-in-mvc) I found `new { onclick = "this.form.submit();" })` but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Foo(Models.FooViewModel Model)
{
    return View(Model);
}
```

**View**

```
<div>
     @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Bars.Count; i++)
     {
        <div class="col-md-2">
           @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Bars[i].Value)
           @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Bars[i].Selected) <-- when checked, do postback to the controller with the model
           @Html.ValueFor(model => model.Bars[i].Text)
         </div>
     }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform it by using ajax call like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#Id').click(function () {
                    var thisCheck = $(this);
                    if (thisCheck.is(':checked')) {
                $.ajax(
                           '@Url.Action( "ActionName" , "Controller" )',
                            {
                               type: 'post',
                               success: function (result) {
                                 //do something on success: show message or update content
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    }else
{
//also  you can do what you want if unchecked. 
}
                });
            });
        </script>
```