# MVC - Postback on clicking a radio button

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-2.0

I am fairly new to MVC. I have a simple problem. I have 3 radio buttons on my mvc asp.net page. I would like to call an action in my controller when I check one of the radio buttons on the page. How do I do a postback in mvc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you had radio buttons like:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female
```

You could add script (**assuming you can use jQuery**) on the page like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(':radio[name="sex"]').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'sex',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { sex: $(':radio[name="sex"]:checked').val() },
                success: function (xhr_data) {
                    alert(xhr_data.someValue);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Assuming you have an action method in the same controller as the one that generated your view:

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult sex(string sex)
    {
        // do something awesome
        return Json(new { someValue = "testing!" });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely what I was looking for. Thanks a ton.

Comment: .change(function ... detection is not very browser friendly... instead use .click(function ...

Answer (score 2):

The answer above only worked for me when I did

```
data: { sex: $('radio[name="sex"]:checked').val() },
```

That is, when I added ':checked' to the selector.

Comment: Agreed, I've incorporated that change (plus the required `:` prefix) into the accepted answer.

Comment: @AakashM Some attribution / recognition in the answer would be nice eh.